# ImageView Does not Align Left using android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening - however I have an imageView I'm attempting to implement on the left side of my screen - however it is centered when I attempt to run the layout and I am unsure why.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ListView_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="left" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downloadbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_download" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I think I know what the problem is, but need more clarity!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mKlGj.jpg

Comment: You want the poster to be aligned to left?

Comment: Added the answer. Check if it works :)

Comment: Your answer disappeared for some reason...

Comment: I am trying to figure out why it didn't solve the problem. I deleted the answer as it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layout of your `imageView1` as follows:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left" />
```

You had set the width of the imageView to fill the parent, which was causing the problem. This snippet fills height, then adjusts width according to the image's dimensions.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need: android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Answer (score 0):

Your image width and height are set to "fill_parent" - try setting them both to "wrap_content".

Comment: I tried the method you suggested... I cannot see imageView1 at all now either. 


http://pastebin.com/dNkaPdF5

Comment: actually change both height and width to use wrap_content and if that still doesn't work try hardcoding a temporary image into the xml to verify that the issue is not in the way you are setting the image at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/downloadbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_download"/>
```

This works for me :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/J3thJ1rk
http://postimg.org/image/6kgww2swx/

I tried as you suggested... it is still appearing in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problems when I was not setting any fixed dimensions on the ***ImageView***. Try giving the ImageView fixed height and width. Did the trick for me.